# restrict external access to actionscript exposed by jwplayer

Tags: security, jwplayer, flash

I have an application that undergone **security scan**, and during the scan of a particular page where **swf** is present, a **attack request** has been triggered to jwplayer.flash.swf and in the attach response it exposed  a  package **com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.events** which contains classes like **GlobalEventDispatcher**, **PlayerEvent**, **LicenseKey** etc, and my concern is like **LicenseKey** class contains  **SHARED_SECRET** attribute which is getting exposed, and we are supposed to remove such shared secret information from the attack response. By googling I found that by changing the property **"allowscriptaccess"** from **"always"** to **"samedomain"** and by adding  the property **"allowNetworking"** with value **"None"** as  below

```
    <object id='MyMovie.swf' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://download.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0' height='100%' width='100%'>
    <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='samedomain'/>
    <param name='allowNetworking' value='none'/>
    <param name='src' value=''MyMovie.swf'/>
    <embed name='MyMovie.swf' pluginspage='/go/getflashplayer' src='MyMovie.swf' height='100%' width='100%' allowScriptAccess='never'>
    </object>
```

May I know if the above two properties  clear the security issues.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: Can I ask how you did the scan? Might use it myself to check my online SWF files..

Comment: No worries. They probably used some installed softare? I just needed a hint like if it was via some browser extension or via some scanning website link etc. Sorry but cant help on this issue. Maybe **[this thread](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/8117888-hiding-jw-player-license-key)** will give you a starting idea to protect the license key?

Comment: Could you post a link to a test page so we can take a look at what's happening?

Comment: @JosieKeller may I know who creates the swf file, I mean will that be created by JWPlayer team ,because when I decompile the swf, I can see that shared_secret native variable.

Comment: @JosieKeller if possible i will share the information that has been exposed, my email id is blcd369@gmail.com, please send a test mail to that id, I will reply to it attaching the exposed information, thanks again

Comment: @VC.One hey check your mail once

Comment: Thanks for the useful scanner link and sorry for my late reply. I hope you made some progress on solving your issue now?